# SQL Remove Mirrored Rows/Pairs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am building a SQL query that tells me the frequency that products have been purchased together.

However, I have encountered an issue where I get mirrored results from my query.

What would be a good way to solve this issue?

**Example output:**

[image]

**Current Query:**

```
SELECT 
x.[Master ID],
x.[Master Title],
y.[Master ID],
y.[Master Title],
COUNT(*)

FROM 
#sku x INNER JOIN #sku y
    ON x.Order_Key = y.Order_Key
AND x.[Master ID] <> y.[Master ID]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an inequality:

```
SELECT x.[Master ID], x.[Master Title], y.[Master ID], y.[Master Title],
       COUNT(*)
FROM #sku x INNER JOIN
     #sku y
     ON x.Order_Key = y.Order_Key AND
        x.[Master ID] < y.[Master ID]
GROUP BY x.[Master ID], x.[Master Title], y.[Master ID], y.[Master Title];
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to have worked! I have used <> before, however your solution did work. Thanks